# Pass a YAML-based property value to @Scheduled annotation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This question is possibly a duplicate of this older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445702/inject-scheduled-fixedrate-value-from-spring-boot-application-yml-file).

I'm working on a **Spring Boot 1.4** application and I have a method of a bean annotated with `@Scheduled`.
I need to pass the cron value to the annotation and, since I'm using YAML based configuration, the cron value is stored in the YAML file (`application.yaml`).

I can't find a way to pass the property value `app.cron` to the annotation.

For instance, this doesn't work

```
@Scheduled(cron = ${app.cron})
```

I have also tried to use EL expression, but no luck.

What is the proper way to pass a YAML based property value to a Spring annotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting it in a Javaconfig first and it should work with EL:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class CronConfig {
    private String cron;
    
    @Bean
    public String cron() {
        return this.cron;
    } 

    public void setCron(String cron) {
       this.cron = cron;
    }
}
```

And use it with `@Scheduled(cron = "#{@cron}")`

I didn't tried this for scheduled Taks but I had similar problem with injecting something to an annotation.

Comment: I already have a class annotated with @ConfigurationProperties, which stores the properties from the yAML file. Do you think the class name makes any difference. If I use EL, I get "bean not found". Also, can you provide the EL expression that you have used?

Comment: ```@Configuration``` properties does not make the properties public to all other components. ```@Config```and ```@Bean``` are the ones adding them to your context. If you just have ```@ConfigurationProperties``` the properties are only bound to the specific component.

Comment: the EL I used was this: ```#{@beanName}```

Comment: I use the @EnableConfigurationProperties on the Config class, and it works fine. I can access the properties in a type-safe way from every other class. What's the complete path of the Config annotation? I can't find it.

Comment: its @Configuration sorry I will update it was written from memory. I will update the answer.

Comment: that did the trick. It's weird because I can inject the configuration class in Spring managed beans using autowired without the Configuration annotation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this:

```
@Configuration
public class CronConfig() {

    @Value("${app.cron}")
    private String cronValue;

    @Bean
    public String cronBean() {
        return this.cronValue;
    } 
}
```

And use it with @Scheduled(cron = "#{@cronBean}")

In this case you'll get the value of "app.cron" from Spring's application.properties or application.yml, the one that you've configured in your project.

Note:

There is a little mistake in the code posted by Dennis:

The method cron() is calling itself:

```
@Bean
public String cron() {
    return this.cron(); // It's calling itself
}
```

So if you run  this code you will get and StackOverFlow Exception.