# Get cron from application.yml file in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, yaml

How to get cron from application.yml.

**application.yml**:

```
cron-expression:
  every: ${CRON:* * * ? * *}
```

**DTO**:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cron-expression")
class ConfigDTO {
    String every;
       
    public String getEvery(){
        return every;

    }
}
```

**Schedule**

```
public Class Schedule{

@Autowired
private ConfigDTO dto;

    @Scheduled(cron = dto.getEvery())
    public void test(){
       Systems.out.println("date time",newDate());
    }
    
    }
```

Is there any possibility to handle like above

Comment: [This answer also help to your questin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642170/pass-a-yaml-based-property-value-to-scheduled-annotation-in-spring-boot/39642594)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPEL (Spring Expression Language) in [@Schedule](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--) expression

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "${cron-expression. every}")
 public void test(){
   Systems.out.println("date time",newDate());
 }
```

Comment: make sure your application properties has that same @DileepBalineni