# How to use Spring Expression Language (SpEL) in groovy? (Per spring scheduler crontab)

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spring-el, spring-scheduled

**Question**

How do I define Spring Expression Language (SpEL) in groovy spring boot project? (Per spring scheduler crontab @scheduled annotation)

**Spring Boot Groovy and Spring EL Scheduler**

Per documentation from the web, I'm dinking around with spring scheduler in my *groovy* spring boot application (2.2.x)

Per this post: [Task scheduling using cron expression from properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306004/task-scheduling-using-cron-expression-from-properties-file)

**Tried this**

I've tried defining my cron expression both as follows:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${appConfig.defaultCron}")
```

and

```
@Scheduled(cron = "#{appConfig.defaultCron}")
```

but get this error:

Attribute 'cron' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but found type 'java.lang.Object' in @org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled

**Analysis**

It seems that the spring 'cron cruncher' sees the "${xxx}" as a Gstring and not as a string

**Question**

How do I get SpringEL work in cron definition in groovy spring boot project?

References
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language

[Inject @Scheduled fixedRate value from Spring Boot application.yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445702/inject-scheduled-fixedrate-value-from-spring-boot-application-yml-file)

Comment: You can't have GStrings in annotation values - only the base types are allowed (String, Class, arrays of those, ...). Have you tried `'${...}'` or `"\${...}"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right. Try to escape that Groovy `$` operator (like this `\$`). So, it comes to Java after compilation as regular symbol. Therefore Spring in the end will be able to resolve that property:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "\${appConfig.defaultCron}")
```